# Edit single row in textfile

Tags: c#, text-files, edit

I have a text file with each row having the same structure 
 ID;Title;comment 
 Example: 1; Hi; some comment.
I want to be able to use a textbox as input for a ID. Then all rows in the textfile with the same id as the one i write in textbox will adjust the comment in the row to "whatever". 
Resulting in like: 1; Hi; Whatever

How can i search in a textfile and replace the contents of the row with the same id?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest to just load everything into memory. Use a good data structure where you can query your data, given the ID. Then loop over your data and set the comment.

Then write back your file. Like that, you can even do queries multiple times reasonably fast.

If it's really a one time operation, you can do it on the fly. Copy line by line into another file. While doing so, check your ID if it matches and adjust your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a csv parser like
http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/

you can simply load the file, loop through the records and save the result

you find a simple example here
http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/discussions/83279